# How to clear express edition database.

Tags: oracle10g, oracle-xe

db has remnants(sequences, views, etc) of former project. How can i entirely clear the express edition(10g) database to work without remnants of the previous project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way is to drop the schema. e.g.

```
DROP USER myuser CASCADE;
```

*WARNING: it's best to assume that you cannot undo this command!*

Alternatively just create a new workspace (if you have apex admin access) which will get a new schema.